# Finding a specific correlation between two data frames, with one being offset by nine months

Tags: r, correlation

This is the next step from a question I asked earlier.  I've got two data frames: one focused on birth data, and one focused on winter weather events.  The aim of my project is to discover whether there exists a simple correlation between extreme winter weather events (i.e. winter storms) and a spike in births nine months later (due to people getting stuck in doors during the storms).

There are several areas with which I'm struggling:

1. I need to factor out less extreme winter weather events from combined.weather.birth$EVENT_TYPE.  The factors currently included are "Frost/Freeze", "Hail", "Heavy Snow", "Ice Storm", "Winter Storm", "Winter Weather", and "Blizzard".  **Of these, I wish to exclude frost/freeze and hail.**
2. I'm having difficulty running the `cff()` function on this data.  As described above, I want to discover and analyze potential correlations between these data sets.  I'm only comparing data in Massachusetts from years 2007-2011.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
correlation1 <- ccf(birth.data$DATE, combined.weather.birth$DATE, lag.max = NULL,
                    type="correlation", plot=TRUE)

correlation2 <- ccf(birth.data$DATE, combined.weather.birth$DATE + combined.weather$EVENT_TYPE, 
                    lag.max = NULL, type="correlation", plot=TRUE)
```

**I need to offset this data by nine months, to account for pregnancy after the winter weather events.**

Here is some information on the data I'm working with:

```
str(combined.weather.birth) <-
    'data.frame':   966 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ EVENT_ID       : int  9620 9619 9623 5391 13835 13845 13844 13847 13846 13836 ...
 $ STATE          : Factor w/ 1 level "MASSACHUSETTS": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ YEAR           : int  2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 ...
 $ MONTH_NAME     : Factor w/ 12 levels "April","August",..: 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ EVENT_TYPE     : Factor w/ 7 levels "Frost/Freeze",..: 6 6 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ INJURIES_DIRECT: int  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ DEATHS_DIRECT  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ DATE           : POSIXct, format: "2007-01-01" "2007-01-01" "2007-01-01" "2007-01-01" ...

str(birth.data) <-
    'data.frame':   60 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ YEAR       : int  2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 ...
 $ MONTH      : Factor w/ 12 levels "April","August",..: 5 4 8 1 9 7 6 2 12 11 ...
 $ BIRTH_TOTAL: num  6250 5833 6570 6227 6858 ...
 $ DATE       : POSIXct, format: "2007-01-01" "2007-02-01" "2007-03-01" "2007-04-01" ..
```

EDIT: I should add that I'm not married to using `cff()` here.  If there is a better function for finding the specified correlation, I am open to learning about it.  I've read a bit about `cor()`, but that doesn't seem appropriate here since it's designed to only work with matrices.

EDIT 2: adding `dput()` data.

```
dput(birth.data)
structure(list(YEAR = c(2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L
), MONTH = structure(c(5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 
10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 
4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 
9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 
2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L), .Label = c("April", "August", "December", 
"February", "January", "July", "June", "March", "May", "November", 
"October", "September"), class = "factor"), BIRTH_TOTAL = c(6250, 
5833, 6570, 6227, 6858, 6735, 6933, 7291, 6385, 6466, 6198, 6221, 
6341, 6051, 6444, 6396, 6781, 6583, 6820, 6803, 6531, 6510, 5627, 
6135, 5976, 5515, 6208, 6261, 6520, 6509, 6834, 6616, 6489, 6318, 
5730, 6040, 5667, 5459, 6162, 6212, 6221, 6194, 6469, 6380, 6342, 
5981, 5853, 5925, 5979, 5414, 6070, 6085, 6242, 6438, 6506, 6459, 
6260, 6158, 5754, 5801), DATE = structure(c(1167609600, 1170288000, 
1172707200, 1175385600, 1177977600, 1180656000, 1183248000, 1185926400, 
1188604800, 1191196800, 1193875200, 1196467200, 1199145600, 1201824000, 
1204329600, 1207008000, 1209600000, 1212278400, 1214870400, 1217548800, 
1220227200, 1222819200, 1225497600, 1228089600, 1230768000, 1233446400, 
1235865600, 1238544000, 1241136000, 1243814400, 1246406400, 1249084800, 
1251763200, 1254355200, 1257033600, 1259625600, 1262304000, 1264982400, 
1267401600, 1270080000, 1272672000, 1275350400, 1277942400, 1280620800, 
1283299200, 1285891200, 1288569600, 1291161600, 1293840000, 1296518400, 
1298937600, 1301616000, 1304208000, 1306886400, 1309478400, 1312156800, 
1314835200, 1317427200, 1320105600, 1322697600), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), .Names = c("YEAR", "MONTH", "BIRTH_TOTAL", "DATE"
), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: 1- Please `deput` your *both* data sets. 2- Please explain what kind of difficulties you are having with the `ccf` function?

Comment: Hi @DavidArenburg: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "deput" the data sets?  With cff, I need to find a way to total EVENT_TYPE by MONTH and by YEAR in combined.weather.birth, and then compare that to BIRTH_TOTAL nine months after each monthly total for combined weather, if that makes sense.

Comment: please run `dput(combined.weather.birth)` and then `dput(birth.data)` and post here

Comment: @DavidArenburg: that quickly put me over the text size limit.  Is there somewhere else I can post this information?  Maybe in another comment?